# How can I convert image url to system.drawing.image

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, itext

I'm using `VB.Net` I have an url of an image, let's say `http://localhost/image.gif`

I need to create a System.Drawing.Image object from that file.

*Notice* save this to a file and then open it is not one of my options 
also i'm using `ItextSharp`

here is my code :

```
Dim rect As iTextSharp.text.Rectangle
        rect = iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER
        Dim x As PDFDocument = New PDFDocument("chart", rect, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        x.UserName = objCurrentUser.FullName
        x.WritePageHeader(1)
        For i = 0 To chartObj.Count - 1
            Dim chartLink as string = "http://localhost/image.gif"
            x.writechart( ** it only accept system.darwing.image ** ) 

        Next

        x.WritePageFooter()
        x.Finish(False)
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could use WebClient class to download image and then MemoryStream to read it:

**C#**

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("http://localhost/image.gif");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

**VB**

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
Dim bytes As Byte() = wc.DownloadData("http://localhost/image.gif")
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
```

Comment: If you were worried about the image not being there, would you put the MemoryStream section in a using statement?

Comment: I would upvote this SO HARD if you provided both ASP.Net MVC and ASP.Net Core solution to the C# route - (ASP.Net Core can't use `WebClient`)

Answer (score 19):

The other answers are also correct, but it hurts to see the Webclient and MemoryStream not getting disposed, I recommend putting your code in a `using`.

Example code:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    using (var imgStream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(imgUrl)))
    {
        using (var objImage = Image.FromStream(imgStream))
        {
            //do stuff with the image
        }
    }
}
```

The required imports at top of your file are `System.IO`, `System.Net` & `System.Drawing`

In VB.net the syntax was `using wc as WebClient = new WebClient() {` etc

Answer (score 4):

You can use HttpClient and accomplish this task async with few lines of code.

```
public async Task<Bitmap> GetImageFromUrl(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
        return new Bitmap(stream);
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp is able to accept Uri's:

```
Image.GetInstance(uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get the Image

```
Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("[URL here]")
Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i do the same think with a page that  `Response.ContentType = "image/png"` i really appreciated

Comment: I could do it the same way, as a any image,  `response.GetResponseStream()` must work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim c As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim FileName As String = "c:\StackOverflow.png"
c.DownloadFile(New System.Uri("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5"), FileName)
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FileName)
```

Comment: Actually, I like his better ^ I was rushing to be first.

Comment: Save the file is not required (you can work it out using a memory stream) and just add potential problems (say you are within a web application that cannot write in the speficied path)