# API Image Request Issue - FileNotFound at URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fromfile

The goal I'm trying to accomplish is simply requesting an image from an API, and returning it to the client-side in the form of an `append` method.

**NO**, I cannot just handle this in client side altogether because of a user/pass requirement for the API.

**NO**, I cannot use `@Url.Action(ImageFromPath)` method in the src of the image.

That said, here's my back-end code:

```
[HttpGet("api/GetImage")]
public ActionResult ImageFromPath()
{
    string URL = "http://user:pass@MYIPADDRESS/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?c=1&authbasic=asdf1234";

    var srcImage = Image.FromFile(URL);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    srcImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

The goal in client-side is:

```
$http.get('/api/GetImage').then(function (response) {
    $("#imgDiv").append('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + response.data + '" />');
});
```

The problem I'm having is on line `srcImage = Image.FromFile(URL)`, with error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
>   CoreCompat.System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

If it makes any difference, the call to the API URL itself requires a couple seconds to return the Image.

Can anyone advise the proper way to get this accomplished? Or at least help in getting my current approach working?

**EDIT** - I've looked at [How can I convert image url to system.drawing.image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801630/how-can-i-convert-image-url-to-system-drawing-image) for an answer, but it only provides solutions using `WebClient` which is not available in ASP.Net Core yet.

Comment: @mjwills I've browsed that question - every answer involves `WebClient` which is not available in ASP.Net Core.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958829/how-do-i-use-the-new-httpclient-from-windows-web-http-to-download-an-image help?

Comment: @mjwills regarding that question - Would you happen to know how to include `Windows.Storage.Streams` and `Windows.Web.Http` in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: The Core alternative (since .NET 4.5 actually...) is HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file from URL, you want to use ***HttpClient***.

### FilesController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DemoWebCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/files/sample.png
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        public async Task<string> Get(string fileName)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                     "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8Ah.jpg?s=48&g=1");
                byte[] content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DemoWebCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<img id="sample-img" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var url = "/api/files/sample.png";
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#sample-img").attr('src', data);
        });
    })
</script>
```

*What you are originally doing is reading a file from file system. If the file is located inside your wwwroot folder, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865058/296861) answer might help you.*

Comment: Unfortunately, the response I get from the Get call is just `data:image/png;base64,` nothing trailing it.

Comment: Please use `https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8Ah.jpg?s=48&g=1` for initial test.

Comment: Yes, the initial test with that URL works. My API call URL doesn't. Your URL already has a `.jpg` extension in it. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If a file's extension is changed, you could just update `image/png` to correct ***MIME Content Type***. For original question, using ***HttpClient*** is the solution. Regarding the image API returning nothing, if you create a new question with that API tag, you might get an answer quick.

Comment: Ok - Your answer helped greatly, will accept - I posted a new question per your recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061263/api-call-using-auth-to-get-image-using-httpclient-not-working

Comment: Win, I've posted a more-refined problem - maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066586/why-does-the-same-asp-net-razor-helper-and-api-call-produce-different-image-outp