# API call using Auth to get image using HttpClient not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, httpclient

I'm attempting to retrieve an image with an API call using `HttpClient` in ASP.Net Core. The problem is, it works with regular images (ones that include the file extension type), but not with my URL.

I don't understand if this has something to do with the API URL involving credentials or not.

Here's a call that works:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8Ah.jpg?s=48&g=1");
byte[] content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(content);
```

And here's mine that doesn't:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
        "http://user:pass@CAMERA-IP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=0&authbasic=aXU8Hu1");
byte[] content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(content);
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Anyone know why this isn't working?

---

Here's more info about that API: http://www.techprosecurity.com/

It's a camera system that's hooked up to a location's IP Address that requires a user/pass to access each camera (channel).

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about that image API?

Comment: @Win I went ahead and edited my question.

Comment: Can you get that image through a browser? Are you sure that url has `http` scheme?

Comment: What error message do you get? Are you sure the image it returns is a png and not a bitmap? What is `authbasic=aXU8Hu1`?

Comment: @IvanR. You can - provided in some browsers, an alert comes up saying you're about to access this page, which by clicking "OK" you see the image. And yes `http`, not `https`

Comment: @Mardoxx - There is no error message. the response is simply `data:image/png;base64,` . The `authbasic` tag is required for the authentication.

Comment: When you click OK, what is the URL of the image? Sounds like you're served up an HTML page from cgi which contains the image -- not just the image itself!

Comment: If you see alert, so maybe that url is not direct image url, but address to some html page with `javascript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by simply embedding the authorization inside the headers:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://CAMERA-IP/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=0");
byte[] myBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
string convertedFromString = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);

return "data:image/png;base64," + convertedFromString;
```