# How to set returned Image Data as ng-src of image in AngularJS

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, rest-client

I've got two ASP.Net Core methods at the moment - one tied to an API call, and one tied to a client-side Razor helper.

They're both located in my `HomeController.cs`.

**API:**

Here's the API call:

```
[HttpGet("api/GetImage")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ImageFromPath()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://IPADDRESS/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=0");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic aYu7GI");
    TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

    RestRequestAsyncHandle handle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));
    RestResponse response = (RestResponse)(await taskCompletion.Task);

    return File(response.RawBytes, "image/png");
}
```

**Razor:**

Here's the Razor helper:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ImageFromPath()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("http://IPADDRESS/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel=0");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic aYu7GI");
    TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();

    RestRequestAsyncHandle handle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));
    RestResponse response = (RestResponse)(await taskCompletion.Task);

    return File(response.RawBytes, "image/png");
}
```

As you can see, the method bodies above are **exactly the same**. One simply has the `HttpGet` annotation.

---

Yet, when paired with their client-side handlers, they produce different results.

**API:**

Client-side handler for API call:

```
<img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}">

$http.get('/api/GetImage', { headers: { 'Accept': 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8' } }).then(function (response) {
    $scope.imageSrc = response.data;
});
```

**Razor:**

Client-side handler for Razor helper:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromPath")" id="img2" />
```

---

Here's where the results show:

**API:**

Here's the API call `preview` in Network tab:

[image: api-preview]

**Razor:**

Here's the Razor Helper call `preview` in Network tab:

[image: razor-preview]

**API:**

Here's the API call `headers` in Network tab:

[image: api-headers]

**Razor:**

Here's the Razor Helper call `headers` in Network tab:

[image: razor-headers]

**API:**

---

Why does the Razor helper actually produce/return an image, yet the API call doesn't? How could I make the API call return an image just like the Razor helper does?

Comment: Both methods cannot be inside HomeController, as they both have same method signature. Anyhow, if you type in `http://localhost:xxx/api/GetImage` inside browser, does it show anything?

Comment: @Win Yes, the image shows. I've also went ahead and tried moving one of the methods to a different Controller - same difference.

Comment: Is your client side AngularJS?

Comment: @Win AngularJS - yes. (I know it's frowned upon, but also using jQuery alongside) hence the inner `$(#img1)...` call in the client-side `$http.get` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need few things. First, you should not access DOM directly inside Angular Controller.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-content></my-content>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module('app')
        .component('myContent', {
            template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.title}}</h1><img src="{{$ctrl.imageSrc}}" />',
            controller: function ($http) {
                var self = this;
                self.title = "Title";
                // Just to verify image work
                //self.imageSrc = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8Ah.jpg?s=48&g=1";
                $http.get('/Home/ImageFromPath').then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    self.imageSrc = response.data;
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Second, you will need to return based64 encoded string.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RestSharp;

namespace DemoWebCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> ImageFromPath()
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient("https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8Ah.jpg?s=48&g=1");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic aYu7GI");
            TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse> taskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
            RestRequestAsyncHandle handle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, r => taskCompletion.SetResult(r));
            RestResponse response = (RestResponse)await taskCompletion.Task;
            return Ok("data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(response.RawBytes));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a question - if I merely change the `return` statement to `return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(response);` I get an error that `response` cannot convert from `RestSharp.RestResponse` to `byte[]`

Comment: You will need to provide byte array in order to convert base64 encoding string.

Comment: Could you show me an example based on my current code? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Trying your above suggestion gives me the error - `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'`

Comment: You will need use `public async Task<string>` instead of `public async Task<ActionResult>`.

Comment: I have tried that just now - I get no image string back, the response from that method is showing `data:image/png;base64,` and that's it.

Comment: In ASP.Net Core, `DownloadData` throws an error because `RestClient` does not contain a definition for `DownloadData` - can you either revise your answer or delete it?

Comment: Sorry, the previous RestSharp code was ASP.NET MVC. I forget that you are using ASP.NET Core. I updated the answer with working code which I tested.

Comment: I could not love you more right now Win, this is awesome - and it really helped me out quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For this fix I have used:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(response.GetBuffer()))
```